# How to set up a simple table view in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, text-files, plist, nstableview

I was wondering if anyone could give me an example or point me to some example code of how to use an NSTableView. I know how to use it in core data but I would like to do this just using plain cocoa code. All I need is a simple add and remove button. Also is it possible to have cocoa write the data to a text file or plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Apple Sample Code.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) Type in table. At present it pulls up four relevant examples.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

Table views are the same with or without core data, but your array controller should manage objects instead of entities.